# Как узнать максимальное значение в массиве?

Tags: php

```
$d_in=array(23, 25,45,78,99);
$m_in = max($d_in[]);
```

Не работает, как записать правильно?

Comment: `$m_in = max($d_in[]);` - что, по-вашему, должен сделать этот код?

Comment: Найти максимальное значение в масиве `$d_in[];`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$d_in=array(23, 25,45,78,99); 
$m_in = max($d_in);
```